# Using Java, how do I accept and categorize a phrase that has numbers and letters in user input?

Tags: java

I'm writing an application that I'd like to be able to accept and hold the user's input of a combination of numbers and letters (06712A1, for instance), and then input that info into an array.  I assume I can't use Integer since there are letters inside it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a String and then validate it by examining all the letters it contains.

What do you mean by "input that info into an array"? Put each character into a separate position in an array?

Comment: No all I meant was just to place the entire string of characters into an index in an array.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: um.. myArray[index] = inputString;

Comment: where myArray is an array of Strings. like so : String[] myArray = new String[10];

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `String` datatype to represent a sequence of characters.

This [tutorial on Strings in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link WW

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous.

I assume you mean that you want to use that String as an `index` to another object. In that case, search for the `java.util.Map` subclass that suits you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer...much appreciated.  And yes that was what I meant regarding adding it into an index in an array.